# Users cannot open workflow task (custom form) - Unexpected exception

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, infopath, powershell

I have created a custom approval task form for an approval workflow. It works fine for me as a site collection administrator, but for normal users (the users getting the task) there is an error message. It says the file cannot be found.

I see in the all files section that the xsn-file is checked out, and I cannot check it in using SPD, but I have read in another post that you can do this with Powershell. However, I have not found out how. Anyone that could help me with that?

Comment: How do I do it directly in the sharepoint site?

Comment: Do users to the tasks have access to the site?

Comment: Yes, they can even create the task, and then they cannot open it afterwards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was solved by Microsoft support.

The problem was that on our site, we had set the "Title" column as required for all content types inheriting from "Document". The forms for workflow-tasks (.xsn) inherited properties from "Document", hence the "Title" column was required.

But there is no place to edit the Title-column, so it was never filled in. Therefore the xsn-file was always checked out, and user's could not see the edited form.

The solution is 
Go to "All files" i SPD 
Right click on the Workflows folder
Double click on the "User Workflow Document" content type
Click "Allow modifications" and save in Designer to make that stick if not already checked.
In the ribbon, select "Administration Web Page"
You will see the columns list. 
If you have a required column (like Title), Click on the column name
Select No for "Require that this column contains information" and OK
Then select "Optional" under column settings
You might get an error that says you can't change the settings but the changes will take place and the title column will become optional
Delete and recreate the custom form.

Now you can edit the form in designer, and publish changes, and the other users can open the custom forms.